# Six paths sage mode

Tags: naruto

Did naruto retain the sage mode given to him by Hagoromo? 
Or was it lost after sealing Kaguya?

Seeing that Sasuke retained the Rinnegan, I believe it is unfain if Naruto lost some of his extra powers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the [Six Paths Sage Mode](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Six_Paths_Sage_Mode), I can find no reference to him having lost the ability, although he apparently always uses it in conjunction with the [Nine Tails Chakra Mode](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nine-Tails_Chakra_Mode).